# ImagePickerController crash

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, cfdata

In a modal view, i have an imageView in which i set the image from gallery or camera.
few times it works perfectly, but as number of selection increases application crashes.I'm using this code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *selectedImage1 = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] fixOrientation];
        NSLog(@"size is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(selectedImage1.size));
        CGImageRef imageRef=[selectedImage1 CGImage];
        float width=CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
        float height=CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
        NSLog(@"length is %f",width*height);
        if (width*height<=12012000.0) {//12MP
            CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
            float length = CFDataGetLength(data);
            CFRelease(data);
            NSLog(@"data==%f ",length);

            if ((length/10)>10485760.0) {//10 MB
                NSLog(@"data length less than 10 mb==%f ",length);
                [imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

                return;
            }
        }else{
            [imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            return;
        }

self.selectedImage=selectedImage1;
            [imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

i guess CFDataRef is causing crash, may be its not released the right way, as i increase the Megapixels(12 to 16MP) application's crashing frequency increases.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use  ELCImagePickerController,

It is Best for you, By using `ELCImagePickerController`
you can select multiple image in gallery and save it in you image view with swipe facility

You can get source code from [Here.](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController#readme)

This might helpful for you.

**Thanks.**

Comment: In my app, user add note with single image attachment,everytime user clicks on my image, he gets the option camera or gallery and whatever he selects i set that image on my imageview,so user can change that image many times as per his wish.So when user select image from gallery multiple times, it crashes.